# How to extend the full width of the child in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a next markup:

[image]

The red block is ListView with a horizontal orientation.
The purple block is just Container for all content.
The white is Container as well but with paddings.

I want to expand the width of the red block on full width. How can I do it? It should look like this:

[image]

Code of the markup:

```
class FifaApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 60.0,
          horizontal: 30.0,
        ),
        color: Color(0xFFffffff),
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.purple,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text("Math Reports"),
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
                height: 170.0,
                child: ListView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  // children: renderItems(), // the example of code without green blocks
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "full width" because the red is already as wide as it can be in the image you've provided.

Comment: @SnakeyHips I updated the topic. See a second image.

Comment: Can tell us what you have already tried and provide the code of your widget ?

Comment: @Muldec the topic was updated. See the code. I've tried to use Stack with hoping to use margins with negative values but it hasn't worked.

Comment: Flutter will voluntarily makes your life harder if you want to deal with overflow. You should instead remove the padding from the white element, and move it to the purple one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Stack as below

```
class FifaApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 60.0,
        ),
        color: Color(0xFFffffff),
        alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              color: Colors.purple,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30.0),
              child: Text(
                "Math Reports",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 170,
              color: Colors.red,
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```